# Track websites for changes

Tags: monitoring, diff, notification

What is a good software to track web page content for changes?

I need to watch several webpages for updates and want to be notified with the modifications highlighted.

The software should be free or an inexpensive one-time payment. The OS does not matter, for PC or mobile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been using **Web Alert** ([Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.webalert)) for quite some time and find it the most useful one.

It's completely free but it is only available on android phones. Web Alert is simple, it has a ton of functionality and it does not seem to affect my battery life or waste my mobile data usage in any noticeable way (although I'm screening seven web pages at the moment).

What I like best is that I can also screen pages with it that first require input (e.g. filling out a form). Also, I don't get spammed by emails and I can specify very exact what and how I want to track.

Answer (score 6):

A good option is to register at:

[Change Detection](http://www.changedetection.com/)

This will track changes for you.  Give the service the URL of the web site(s) of interest and it will email you when it sees a change.

Answer (score 4):

[Trackly](https://trackly.io/) is worth a look, it will email you an image of the webpage with changes highlighted. Hourly and daily checks available.

It works well even with very dynamic web pages using tons of javascript and other fanciness.

It's free while in beta.